# getting the hexvalue of an array

Tags: arrays, perl, hex

this is **part** of my perl Code:

```
    my $start= @list[0];
    my @Type=@list[1,2];
    my @ID =@list[6,5,4,3];
    my $date=@list[10,9,8,7];
```

Decimal is a list that I filled by reading data from a binary file, I want to save data into an output file according to their respected Format, **@decimal** for **start** and **hex** for **@Type** and **@ID**  and **yyy.mm.dd** for **@date**.

i have looked into this but all I could find is :

```
my $hex = sprintf("0x%X", $d);
```

which I can't use for an Array necessarly. also i couldnt find much concerning date and time Format in perl. Can you Point me in the Right direction.

Comment: What do you mean by "the date Format"?

Comment: ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`. There are some glaring errors this would catch in the code you posted.

Comment: @ikegami yyyy,mm,dd

Comment: What do you want to convert to that format? An epoch time stamp?

Comment: @ikegami ok, please calm down, I do Mention that this is PART of my Code. i have strict and warnings in the beginning

Comment: Are you saying you ignored the warnings? But more importantly, there's an outstanding question. You said what what you want to convert to, but not what you want to convert from.

Comment: Why in the world are you using a bunch of single-element list slices?

Comment: `my @ID = @list[6,5,4,3]` is a better way to use arrays.

Comment: It would really help if you could show us what is in `@list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map` function is useful for applying an operation to all the elements of an array.

```
@hexType = map { sprintf("0x%x",$_) } @Type;
@hexID = map { sprintf("0x%x",$_) } @ID;
```

Answer (score 3):

You say:

> i have strict and warnings in the beginning

But here's a simple test version of your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my @list = (1 .. 10);

my $start= @list[0];
my @Type=(@list[1], @list[2]);
my @ID =(@list[6], @list[5], @list[4], @list[3]);
my $date=(@list[10], @list[9], @list[8], @list[7]);
```

And when I run that, I get this list of warnings:

```
Useless use of array slice in void context at list line 11.
Useless use of array slice in void context at list line 11.
Useless use of array slice in void context at list line 11.
Scalar value @list[0] better written as $list[0] at list line 8.
Scalar value @list[1] better written as $list[1] at list line 9.
Scalar value @list[2] better written as $list[2] at list line 9.
Scalar value @list[6] better written as $list[6] at list line 10.
Scalar value @list[5] better written as $list[5] at list line 10.
Scalar value @list[4] better written as $list[4] at list line 10.
Scalar value @list[3] better written as $list[3] at list line 10.
Scalar value @list[10] better written as $list[10] at list line 11.
Scalar value @list[9] better written as $list[9] at list line 11.
Scalar value @list[8] better written as $list[8] at list line 11.
Scalar value @list[7] better written as $list[7] at list line 11.
```

So either this isn't your actual code, of you don't care about asking people to help you with code that is full of errors.

Comment: this is not my Code. I am not asking for modification for my Code but rather what do you do if you want to apply a function (whatever it is) that usually takes a singular variable and you want it applied to an Array. this small part of my was an example.

Comment: @waffles123: Ok. But this small part was flawed. And it's rude to all people to help with code that generates warnings (unless, of course, you're asking for help getting rid of the warnings).

Comment: **Your** Code generated warnings. Again I used that part as an example while asking for a general solution. My complete Code is about 300 lines, I can't post it all. it seems like you didn#t read my quesion underneath the Code but rather just went testing. sorry if that consumed your precious time.

Comment: @waffles123: I'm not asking that you post your whole code. I'm asking that you make sure the section you post runs without warnings.